# How do i disable Oracle Unified Auditing for RMAN?

Tags: oracle, audit, rman

I currently have Oracle's Unified Auditing enabled, but I noticed that RMAN is also listed in the Unified_Audit_Trail. The value RMAN_AUDIT is displayed in the Audit_Type instead of Standard when i look at the Unified_Audit_Trail. I have already searched everywhere online. So far I only know that this is a component, but I don't know how to disable RMAN_Audit.

Comment: Unified Audit Trail includes all components - that's the point of it. Since RMAN (backup and recovery operations) requires elevated privileges it is audited by default. Rather than disable it, just filter for the audits you want in your SQL when selecting from the audit trail.

Comment: Current Requirements are for them not to be even included. So there is no way of disabling RMAN Auditing?

Comment: _"Current Requirements are for them not to be even included"_  Current requirements are not based on reality.  Explain to those insisting on such foolishness that 1) it cannot be turned off, and 2) it is easy enough to simply filter them out of any reports.

Comment: I'm wondering what Legal would have to say about those requirements. (They usually enforce Auditing being ON. Especially for Production systems)

Comment: I would agree with everyone else here so far in that it is *highly inadvisable* - even if it *was* possible - to disable auditing of what are essentially super-user privileges. Just say "no".